# Replace line containing a string but leave the last character if it is a comma

Tags: linux, sed

I want to do a string replacement of a line containing TEXT and and leave a `,` symbol at the end *if* it is there.

Examples:

I want to replace `"value": 5,` with `"new-value": 0,`

And `"value": 5` with `"new-value": 0`

I currently have this:

```
sed -i 's/.*"cost":.*,$/    "cost": 0/' $FILE_NAME
```

However, it will always remove the `,` from the end. Any suggestions?

Comment: Add a `,` at the end of your replacement string?

Comment: No it's a json file and sometimes the value is at the end of where the curly braces are, so sometimes it doesn't need a , and sometimes it does. So I want to leave the , there if its on the line but replace the rest.

Comment: I you use a JSON aware tool such as jq, you can produce a much more robust solution than by manipulating the raw string with sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i 's/."cost":.\(,\)\?$/ "cost": 0\1/' $FILE_NAME
```

Note that this will only work for single-digit cost values.

Though you could use

```
sed -i 's/."cost":[0-9]\+\(,\)\?$/ "cost": 0\1/' $FILE_NAME
```

to handle an arbitrary number of digits.

Comment: Damn dude not sure how that works completely, but thanks haha.